Set white color for status bar and navigation bar with dark text
I want to set white background color for status bar and navigation bar and black color for text
<item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/white</item>
<item name="android:statusBarColor" >@color/AppBack</item>
<item name="android:windowLightStatusBar" tools:targetApi="m">true</item>

But when I try to darken the color of the navigation bar icon with the code below, the color of the status bar text turns white
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_NAVIGATION_BAR);
    }

Note: This problem exists in Android 13

try this:
<item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/white</item>
<item name="android:statusBarColor" >@color/AppBack</item>
<item name="android:windowLightStatusBar" tools:targetApi="m">true</item>
<item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>

